# How to get two tables data using single mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Following is my tables which is student id is common field in both tables. I want to get both tables data in single query.Also get recent data of student.

```
 table A:

        student_id    name     surname        email
        ------------------------------------------------
              1       ABC       LLL       abc@gmail.com
              2       PQR       SSS       pqr@gmail.com


        Table B:

          student_id  Assignment_Id  Assignment_Name      last_submited   
         ---------------------------------------------------------------------
              2            1             asign_1            sub_0001
              1            2             asign_2            sub_0002 
              2            3             asign_2            sub_0003
```

I want exact output like:-

```
student_id   Assignment_Id         email      last_submited
--------------------------------------------------------------
    2             3               pqr@gmail.com      sub_0003
```

I have used following query for getting recent record but confused how to get email id along with this.

```
SELECT assignment_id,
       student_id,
       last_submited
FROM tableB
WHERE student_id= '2'
ORDER BY assignment_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: mysql or sql server ... can't be both

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a `JOIN`

```
select  tableB.assignment_id, 
        tableB.student_id, 
        tableB.last_submited,
        tableA.email
from    tableB INNER JOIN
        tableA ON tableB.student_id = tableA.student_id
where   tableB.student_id= '2' 
order by tableB.assignment_id desc 
limit 1
```

`INNER JOINs` are used to return data where the data is in both tables (so en entry would exist in tableA and tableB).

`LEFT JOINs` are used when you wish to retrieve all data from tableA and those values that are available in tableB.

So, lets say you had

```
TABLEA
-------
1
2
```

and

```
TABLEB
-------
1

SELECT *
FROM TABLEA INNER JOIN
TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID
```

would return

```
1,1
```

Whereas

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA LEFT JOIN
TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID
```

would return

```
1,1
2,NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Astander its working for me perfectly and thanks for explaining nicely

Answer (score 1):

Join both the tables,

```
SELECT B.assignment_id,
       B.student_id,
       A.email_id ,
       B.last_submited
FROM tableB 'B',
            tableA 'A'
WHERE B.student_id= '2'
  AND A.student_id=B.student_id
ORDER BY assignment_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `join`

```
SELECT a.student_id,
       b.Assignment_id,
       a.email,
       b.last_submitted
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
WHERE a.student_id= '2'
ORDER BY b.assignment_id DESC LIMIT 1
```